Using Bicep to add an MsTeams channel to an Azure Bot Resource
When attempting to add an MSTeams channel to my deployment I receive a CHANNEL_NOT_SUPPORTED error.
The Bicep I'm using looks something like this.
resource azureBot 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices@2021-03-01' = {
  name: botName
  location: location
  kind: 'azurebot'
  sku: azureBotSku
  properties: {
    displayName: **
    iconUrl: **
    endpoint: **
    msaAppId: **
    msaAppTenantId: ** 
    msaAppMSIResourceId: **
    msaAppType: 'UserAssignedMSI'
    tenantId: tenantId
    luisAppIds: []
    schemaTransformationVersion: '1.3'
    isCmekEnabled: false
  }

  resource teamsChannel 'channels' = {
    name: 'TeamsChannel'
    kind: 'azureBot'
    properties: {
      channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
      properties: {
        acceptedTerms: true
        isEnabled: true
      }
    }
  }
}

I can add the channel manually through the portal just fine.

Could you please try with the below snippet?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit-samples/blob/1e2936283d3fd51d9aeb50da301d23cbb0a07508/bot-sso-docker/infra/botRegistration/azurebot.bicep#L30
// Connect the bot service to Microsoft Teams
resource botServiceMsTeamsChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2021-03-01' = {
parent: botService
location: 'global'
name: 'MsTeamsChannel'
properties: {
channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
}
}

This worked for me, though I think the location property was also a requirement.

@Meghana-MSFT If you would like to post an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will answer it myself.

@user26123493 - Posted my answer.

Could you please try with the below snippet?
https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit-samples/blob/dev/bot-sso-docker/infra/botRegistration/azurebot.bicep#L30
// Connect the bot service to Microsoft Teams
resource botServiceMsTeamsChannel 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels@2021-03-01' = {
  parent: botService
  location: 'global'
  name: 'MsTeamsChannel'
  properties: {
    channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
  }
}


Strangely, the name of this resource also needs  - 'name: 'MsTeamsChannel''.

I have also received the same error when I tried with the resource teams block as you.
So, to add a teams channel to Bot resource, use channelName under bot services resource as shown below. Avoid using a separate teams resource block for adding it.
Modified bicep code:
param location string = 'westus'
resource azureBot 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices@2023-09-15-preview' = {
  name: 'botNamejah'
  location: location
  kind: 'azurebot'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'newdisplay'
    msaAppId: 'axxxxx89'
    msaAppTenantId: 'xxxxx'
    msaAppMSIResourceId: '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/newuser'
    endpoint: 'https://myrg.azure-api.net'
    msaAppType: 'UserAssignedMSI'
    tenantId: ''
    luisAppIds: []
    schemaTransformationVersion: '1.3'
    channelName: 'MsTeamsChannel'
    isCmekEnabled: false
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:


